# How to create custom popup based on success insert or failure mySQL?

Tags: mysql, popup, jqmodal

I would like to have a customer popup window appear on a page after the insert to mySQL is completed.

I have the "header" going to a particular page, but I would also like to have a custom popup window appear after the page loads.

Here is my current php script.  Everything works, but I need to add a popup window based on a success or failure.

```
    <?
.........

    if ($result) {
    header("location: inv_fc.php");  //NEED TO ADD A CUSTOM POPUP FOR SUCCESS
    }
    else {
    header("location: inv_fc.php");  //NEED TO ADD A CUSTOM POPUP FOR FAILURE

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can't you just write the necessary jQuery-JS to the page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Start the session with `session_start()`, and then set the session variables using the `$_SESSION` array. Then in `inv_fc.php`, check for the existence of the session variable (you must also call `session_start()` in this file).

So, something like

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['success'] = ($result) ? TRUE : FALSE;

header('location: inv_fc.php');

// inside inv_fc.php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['success'] == TRUE) {
  // do success stuff
} else {
  // do failure stuff
}
```

where we've used the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 0):

```
header("location: inv_fc.php?success=" . ($result ? 'y' : 'n'));
```

would be the easiest, then just look for that 'sucess' query parameter in the new page:

```
if ($_GET['success'] == 'y') {
     ... success ...
} else {
     ... epic fail ...
}
```

Comment: don;t understand the script for the new page

Comment: Oops, guess I accidentally a word there.

Comment: Once the I load the page, inv_fc.php, I need a pop up window to appear on the same page.  Not sure how you're doing this.

Comment: yes, you'd put the code for the pop up to appear in the success/epic fail sections.